# need to downgrade to an older kernel in 22.04 from a live environment

Tags: boot, kernel

Current kernel under 22.04.1 Linux 5.15.0-46-generic is not booting, takes me to initramfs. I know it was working under the previous kernel version because I could boot from that kernel, which now however when I updated to 22.04.1 is gone. I would like to try fixing it by installing an older version kernel from the live USB environment. How do I do that? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**Try the easier option first:**

- Boot, hit ESC ONCE as the "BIOS" text appears,
- this should make the grub boot selection menu appear.
- Look up the recovery mode option for the previous kernel,
- boot it,
- do "fsck" (make sure disks are writable),
- enable network,
- drop to root prompt,
- uninstall the failing kernel,
- do `update-grub` and
- `update-initramfs -u`, then
- `reboot`